# Deep writing data to shared memory structure in C failed

Tags: c

I used shm_open() to apply for a piece of shared memory in c language, and then used mmap() to convert it to the Struct MinHeap* type. Since the MinHeap struct has struct Element elementd[16] inside,how could  I modify the value of elements?I did as follwed but failed when the program run into init_elm() and tried to assign the flag.

```c
struct Element{
    int flag;
    int id;
    char name[32];
};


struct MinHeap{
    struct Element elements[16];
    int size;
    int capacity;
};

void init_elm(struct Element* elm){
    elm->flag=FREE;//---------------------------------WRONG HERE
    elm->id=-1;
    strcpy(elm->name,"Unamed");
}

void init_heap(struct MinHeap* heap){
    for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++){
        init_elm(&(heap->elements[i]));
    }
    heap->elements[0].id=INT_MIN;
    heap->capacity=CAPACITY;
    heap->size=0;
}

char* shm_file = SHM_FILE_NAME;
size_t  shm_size = 32*sizeof(struct MinHeap);
key_t shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_FILE_NAME,O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd,shm_size);
struct MinHeap* mhp_p = (struct MinHeap*)mmap(0,shm_size,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,shm_fd,0);/*MinHeap pointer to shared memory*/
init_heap(mhp_p);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, that some of those funcs (mmap etc.) really initialize the shared mem's content accordingly. are you sure, that i.e. mhp[0] contains a proper pointer that points to a "struct Element" in shared mem (which would indeed result in requiring additional 32 * 8 byte (32 pointers) somewhere)?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Synopsis: I think you're misreading here; the structs all contain raw arrays, not pointers; the data is all allocated in a single block, so it doesn't need separate allocation for the components. `mhp_p` is a legal pointer to 32 `struct MinHeap`s (zero-initialized), each of which contain, internally, no pointers involved, 16 `struct Element`s (which are of course zero-initialized along with the rest of the `MinHeap` containing them). There's only one pointer involved, the rest is all a single contiguous block allocation.

Comment: Thank you all for your answering, and I guess I still need to learn more about pointers and the array, also the diffs between them...^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init elm() method appears to be proper based on the code you gave, and the statement elm->flag=FREE; ought to function as intended.

One more potential problem can be seen in the code is you are trying to modify a shared memory segment that is read-only by using the mmap() function with the PROT_READ flag. You need to use the mmap() function with the PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE flags as below

`struct MinHeap* mhp_p = (struct MinHeap*)mmap(0,shm_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,shm_fd,0);`

This will allow you to modify the shared memory segment using the MinHeap pointer, including the elements of the struct Element array.

**Additional suggestion**

The line strcpy(elm->name,"Unamed"); in the code you submitted may be a problem. While accessing the shared memory region, a segmentation fault or other undefinable behaviour may occur if the name field of the Element struct is not properly initialised.

The shared memory region's elements can be changed using the same syntax as a standard struct pointer. For instance, you could take the following actions to change the flag field of the first element in the shared memory region:

`mhp_p->elements[0].flag = NEW_VALUE;`

where NEW VALUE denotes the value that should be entered into the flag field.

Comment: The `strcpy` is not a problem; `name` is an array, not an uninitialized pointer; it need not be initialized to copy into it, as long as what is being copied (including `NUL` terminator) fits in the array. The `PROT_READ` thing is the *entire* issue; you should really make that the focus of the answer, not bury it under several paragraphs of "your code is fine".

Comment: Ohhhh,thank you.The problem is just in the discription "PROT_READ",which doesn't allow the shared memory to be written.

Comment: And other suggestions I will also consider to take.^_^